# Add property to object in reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to add a property to my state `currentDrink`:

```
{
    currentDrink: {
      ...action.payload
    },
    ...state
}
```

I would like my state to be:

```
currentDrink: {
    prop: 1,
    prop: 2,
    ...etc
},
```

My state only every contains one property.

Comment: Do you have any typos? You cannot have 2 key with the same value like your `prop` attributes

Comment: we need to see more code

Answer (score 1):

The problem is very trivial, the order in which the spread operator syntax is used decides the final result

So

```
{
    currentDrink: {
      ...action.payload
    },
    ...state
  }
```

is different from

```
 {
    ...state,
    currentDrink: {
      ...action.payload
    }
  }
```

In the first case, if state already contains, `currentDrink` property it will your custom change to `currentDrink` will be overwritten with the states one.

In the second second, case the custom currentDrink object will override what is present in state, if at all. However

```
currentDrink: {
    ...action.payload
}
```

will destructure action.payload and assign it to currentDrink and override whatever was present in the currentDrink object in state.

You should probably use

```
{
    ...state,
    currentDrink: {
      ...state.currentDrink,
      ...action.payload
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get a chance to try out this answer. Let me know if you face any issues